# ForkJoinFramwork, call compute() directly without explicit ForkJoinPool/ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, forkjoinpool

Q: What happens when the compute() method, in a class "X" that extends RecursiveAction/Task, is directly called?

**Without calling a ForkJoinPool explicitly** like the following:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
ForkJoinTask<?> task = new X(...);
pool.invoke(task);
```

Instead a function call like the following still produce a similar result:

```
// X extends RecursiveAction/Task<V>, which also means it is a subclass of ForkJoinTask.
X x = new X(...);
x.compute();
```

**What happens when the fork()/invokeAll() method inside class X is called (explicit ExecutorService is absent)?**

My assumption would be, when an fork() or invoke() method inside the extended class X is called, a new task is automatically submitted to the **ForkJoinPool.commonPool()**, if no pool is explicitly specified. But I couldn't find any document that specifies this behavior.

(Citation from the oracle documentation that might be relative)

> A "main" ForkJoinTask begins execution when it is explicitly submitted
> to a ForkJoinPool, or, if not already engaged in a ForkJoin
> computation, commenced in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() via fork(),
> invoke(), or related methods.

Any info or keywords would be appreciated.

A code snippet (note the "othertask.fork()"):

```
class X extends RecursiveTask<Double>{
    private Double[] numbersToBeOperated;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    
    public X(Double numbersToBeOperated, int start, int end){
        // define the fields, i.e., this.* = *;
    }
    @Override
    protected Double compute(){
        if(taskDividedToBaseCase){
            // do works
        } else {
            int middle = start + ((end - start) / 2);
            RecursiveTask<Double> otherTask = new X(numbersToBeOperated, start, middle);
            otherTask.fork(); // what happens here, when compute() is directly called?
            return new X(numbersToBeOperated, middle, end).compute() + otherTask.join();
            // or invokeAll(new X(...), new X(...)); if RecursiveAction
        }
    }
}
// then instantiate X and call X.compute() directly.
```

Comment: How could it be said more explicit than “*commenced in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() via fork()*” in the text you already cited? Well, you could look into [the documentation of `fork()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#fork--), to find out that right the first sentence answers your question literally.

Comment: @Holger Hey, thanks a lot. That indeed solves the problem. Should've looked into that earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask<V>.fork()`:

> Arranges to asynchronously execute this task in the pool the current task is running in, if applicable, or using the
> ForkJoinPool.commonPool() if not inForkJoinPool().

It do goes to the commonPool().

Also thanks @Holger for pointing to this documentation.